# Qual e a diferenca entre Kotlin data class e Scala case class?

Tags: java, java-8, kotlin, scala, data-class

Em Scala temos `case classes`, por exemplo:

```
case class Pessoa(nome: String, sobrenome: String)
```

e em Kotlin temos `data classes`:

```
data class Pessoa( val nome: String, val sobrenome: String )
```

Qual a diferença entre as duas?

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que procurava saber? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora? Se não, precisa que algo mais seja melhorado?

Answer (score 7):

Essencialmente elas são usadas para o mesmo objetivo, ou seja, elas definem um [*record*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_(computer_science)). Portando elas ganham automaticamente os principais métodos necessários, entre eles os métodos "acessores" para os campos, os de equalidade, *hash code*, representação textual (`toString`) e cópia.

Em Scala também são providos métodos de `apply()` e `unapply()` para as [`case class`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/case-classes.html)es.

Em Kotlin, nas [`data class`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html)es, são providos métodos que ajudam a seleção de padrões de forma semelhante ao `unapply()`, ainda que menos poderosos, a linguagem não exige a existência do `apply()`. Ela também tem métodos "acessores" Java Beans, além dos normais que estão disponíveis para qualquer classe em Kotlin. Não é possível usar herança em registros. Ela exige o uso de `var` ou `val` para os parâmetros para indicar que são campos.

Java em versões mais novas tem um mecanismo semelhante chamado *record*.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Kotlin/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Uma coisa interessando do Scala é o método `copy` também.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type, outro tópico que Scala `case class` se baseiam (não sei à respeito Kotlin).