# Quais as principais diferenças entre Kotlin e Scala?

Tags: característica-linguagem, scala, kotlin

Já estão bem claras as [diferenças entre Kotlin e Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/206365/63110), tais como:

- Mais conciso (redução de até 40% do código)
- Null Safety
- Inferência de tipos
- Data class
- Interoperável com Java

Porém, todas estas características já existem no Scala, uma linguagem que também roda na JVM.

**Assim, quais as principais diferenças entre Kotlin e Scala? Quais são as lacunas existentes no Scala que motivaram o Kotlin?**

Comment: Sucintamente, as principais diferenças entre Kotlin e Scala é que Kotlin é mais rápido e mais fácil de ler.

Comment: Uma delas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/139839/101

Comment: @acklay porque?

Comment: `Porém, todas estas características já existem no Scala, uma linguagem que também roda na JVM (...) Quais são as lacunas existentes no Scala que motivaram o Kotlin?` Não, não é por existirem lacunas que as coisas são criadas. O ecossistema das linguagens funciona a maior parte do tempo assim: https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: @bigown eu li algumas comparações e essa foi uma conclusão que tirei em relação ao funcionamento das duas. Esse [projeto no Github](https://github.com/SidneyXu/AndroidDemoIn4Languages) possui um uma comparação usando 4 formas diferentes. Java, Groovy, Scala e Kotlin. Não acredito que teve alguma tendenciosidade nesta análise.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Imagino que está querendo saber porque criaram Kotlin se Scala já resolve esses problemas, ou seja, por que criaram um Java melhor que o Java se Scala já faz isso? Se não for isso imagino que a pergunta é duplicata.

Talvez o maior motivo seja porque Scala até é interessante, mas não é exatamente um Java melhor que o Java. Ela pendeu muito para o lado funcional e cria dificuldades para o programador médio acostumado com uma linguagem essencialmente imperativa. Kotlin mantém o espírito imperativo do Java muito mais que Scala fez. Os problemas mais típicos que o Java resolve são resolvidos de forma mais adequada em Kotlin.

Verdade seja dita que Kotlin começou ser desenvolvida quando Scala estava em um estágio menos avançado e tinha mais problemas do que tem hoje para o programador médio. Scala está mais palatável.

Para atender os requisitos da linguagem um compilador Scala não conseguiu ser tão eficiente. Já Kotlin foi pensada para ter uma sintaxe que favorecesse a compilação. Podemos dizer que esse é um [motivo oficial](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2622405/java/jetbrains-readies-jvm-based-language.html). Embora pra falar a verdade acho o compilador de Kotlin bem lento (talvez Scala seja trágico, acontece muito em linguagens que oferecem facilidades demais).

Ali fala também que o conjunto de características não agradava. E este geralmente é o motivo para se criar uma nova linguagem. Raramente se cria algo novo em, linguagens de mercado, apenas se faz o já existente de uma forma diferente com um conjunto e intersecções específicas diferente do que já existe, e isso faz diferença.

Especificamente Kotlin:

- é um pouco mais explícita que Scala. Linguagens funcionais tendem a ser muito concisas sacrificando um pouco a legibilidade. Kotlin optou por ser mais verbosa onde pode acrescentar algo importante para o código, não tanto quanto Java.
- é um pouco mais voltada para OOP que Scala.
- interopera com Java melhor.
- compila para e interopera com JavaScript.
- possui [Extensions](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html).
- é segura para uso de valores nulos na própria linguagem.
- tem [*smart casts*](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts).
- usa [*inline functions*](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#inline-functions) para eficiência onde é possível.
- trata a [delegação](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html) como [primeira classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227485/101).
- pode chamar uma função pelo seu nome como uma [referência](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references).

Por outro lado ela não tem:

- o [modelo Actor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) implementado na linguagem.
- geradores (`yield`).
- tipos por valor, mas terá quando Java 10 implementar, o que deve ser mais compatível com Java.
- [tipagem estrutural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system).
- XML na linguagem.
- criação de novos operadores
- [tipos existenciais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types).
- [tipagem dependente do caminho](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693067/what-is-meant-by-scalas-path-dependent-types).
- macros

Certamente tem outras coisas que eu não lembro ou não achei. Obviamente tem [pequenas diferenças de sintaxe](https://github.com/SidneyXu/AndroidDemoIn4Languages). Tem diferenças pequenas em cada mecanismo, por exemplo [Qual e a diferenca entre Kotlin data class e Scala case class?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/139839/101). E isso pode ter ficado defasado ao longo do tempo, tem coisas que a linguagem não tem agora, mas é uma questão de tempo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Kotlin/Conceptual.md).