# Em uma linguagem de programação, o que diferencia um cidadão de primeira classe do restante?

Tags: terminologia, independente-de-linguagem, paradigma-de-programação

De uma forma simples, **o que é** um "cidadão de primeira classe" em uma linguagem de programação? E, principalmente, **como se diferencia** algo que é um cidadão de primeira classe de algo que não o é?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Segundo a Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen) é quando um recurso da linguagem permite ser usado de todas as formas que normalmente é possível usar nela.

Se um recurso pode ser criado na linguagem mas não pode ser atribuído para uma variável, ou passado como argumento de uma função, ou retornado, aquele recurso específico não é um cidadão de primeira classe, ele não pode fazer tudo o que os de primeira classe pode, há limitação na sua atuação.

[O termo é muito usado em funções](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) e esse é um bom exemplo. Essencialmente qualquer linguagem pode criá-las, mas nem todas podem tê-las atribuídas para variáveis ou passadas como argumentos ou retorno. As linguagens que permitem isso tem a função como uma cidadã de primeira classe.

Tem linguagens que até permitem fazer isso mas através de um mecanismo obscuro secundário, ou seja, dá para fazer, mas não é porque a linguagem "conscientemente" resolveu ter isso de forma facilitada e não tem uma sintaxe própria para isso. Então conseguir fazer é algo colateral à intenção da linguagem, e portando é de segunda classe.

Não ter um literal para aquilo provavelmente faz o recurso ser de segunda classe, ainda que exista.

No artigo indica que o termo foi criado pelo Christopher Strachey em 1960 provavelmente para diferenciar de formas precárias. O termo hoje é muito usado como marketing para dizer que a linguagem possui algo melhor que outras, mesmo que nem sempre seja o caso.

Já vi sendo usado em contextos um pouco diferentes e não sei se é certo. Encaram como coisas "nativas" na linguagem como sendo de primeira classe, em oposição a coisas que dá para fazer com algum esforço. Por exemplo assincronismo que é nativo em C# 5 para cima, embora sempre deu para fazer de forma convoluta. Mas você não pode usar `async` em qualquer lugar da linguagem, então ele não seria de primeira classe pela definição mais formal.

Há quem diga que a linguagem precisa ter poder de criar um recurso pelo próprio código para ele ser considerado de primeira classe. Por essa definição, torna as linguagens dinâmicas mais propensas a terem mecanismos de primeira classe. Me parece que essa proposição é um pouco mais estrita e nem sempre aceita em todos os círculos. Não costuma ser assim no livro [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-12.html#call_footnote_Temp_121) que é meio que uma bíblia da computação.

Mas há quem diga que na definição menos estrita apenas coloca que o recurso deve poder ser usado em qualquer coisa da linguagem. Não sei se é certo porque é raro ter algo que pode ser usado tão universalmente assim, precisaria de uma definição de onde pode ou não. Nenhuma linguagem é tão livre que algo pode ser usado em tudo. Como muitos termos, há polêmica.

Na [resposta do Norman Ramsey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2582804/221800), que entende bem do assunto, ele coloca, por exemplo, que um `int` em Java não é de primeira classe porque não pode ser herdado. É uma forma de pensar.

Só não ache que ter algo como sendo de segunda classe é inerentemente ruim. Tem coisas que ser de primeira classe é péssimo. Pode dar poder, mas pode dar dor de cabeça lidar com aquilo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).