# Em uma linguagem de programação, tipos primitivos são sempre cidadãos de primeira classe?

Tags: independente-de-linguagem, paradigma-de-programação

É correto afirmar que todo tipo primitivo é um cidadão de primeira classe em uma linguagem de programação? Se não, por qual motivo? Isso pode variar de linguagem para linguagem?

Comment: O que quer dizer "cidadãos"? Nunca ouvi esse termo antes em programação.

Comment: @Articuno, [aqui](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cidad%C3%A3os_de_Primeira_Classe) uma referência.

Comment: @Articuno [outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227485/18246)

Comment: Não é fácil responder isso, é um pouco ambíguo. Eu acho que o tipo não é, o valor sim, mas há controvérsias.

Comment: @bigown Em Ruby, por exemplo, "tudo é um objeto". Você pode chamar um método diretamente do número 10, por exemplo (10.to_s). FIca dificil saber o que é o que não é um cidadão de primera classe nessa linguagem de acordo com as definições que tem por ai.

Comment: Isso não é verdade, isso é um marketing da linguagem, tem um monte de coisa nela que não é objeto :) Isso que você mostrou essencialmente qualquer linguagem pode. Mesmo que você diga que todos valores são objetos, isto pode ser dito de todas linguagens. Carece de melhor definição. Aí a linguagem pode dar uma definição que só atende seu interesse, então fica complicado.