# Qual é o First-Class de Python?

Tags: python, característica-linguagem, paradigma-de-programação

O first-class da linguagem Java são objetos, pois não se pode criar nada em Java sem a utilização de classes. Já em Haskell, seguindo o mesmo critério anterior, o first-class são funções. No caso de Python, o que é considerado o first-class da linguagem?

Comment: Tudo pode ser *first class*, nada precisa ser, então querer escolher um não faz sentido. Essa ideia de que objetos são *first-class* em Java é falsa. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227485/101 Na verdade sequer a ideia que tudo depende de classe, que tudo é orientado a objeto é verdadeira.

Answer (score -4):

Tudo em python é um first-class, pois tudo é object e object é first-class. Ou seja uma classe, uma função, um método... são atribuíveis, referenciáveis e etc, utilizam a estrutura de dados padrão da linguagem.
Já em java isso não é verdade.
Segue uma demonstração:

Python:

```
class A:
  pass

def test():
  pass

print(isinstance(test,object))
a = 1
print(isinstance(a,object))
a = A()
print(isinstance(a,object))
print(isinstance(A,object))
```

Java:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args){
        int a = 1;
        System.out.println( a instanceof Object);
    }
}
```

Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html

Porém em java é possível dizer que os objetos e os tipos primitivos são first-class.

Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68312/discussion-on-answer-by-ettore-leandro-tognoli-qual-e-o-first-class-de-python)