# Os métodos são objetos em Ruby?

Tags: ruby, método, objetos

O Ruby tem a classe `Proc`, que é [definida na documentação](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html) como

> blocks of code that have been bound to a set of local variables. Once
>   bound, the code may be called in different contexts and still access
>   those variables.

É essa classe que possibilita os [*lambdas*](https://gist.github.com/Integralist/9994331) nessa linguagem.

Além do `Proc` tem a classe [`Method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Method.html), que não tem um descritivo na documentação além de

> Public Instance Methods

A dúvida é se as funções não-anônimas, como

```
def greet
  "hello there"
end
```

também são objetos. Se forem objetos, são da classe `Proc` ou `Method`? E por que são ou não são objetos?

[Com certeza, de maneira abstrata, são objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/205482/em-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-o-que-%C3%A9-um-objeto). Mas são objetos dentro do Ruby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dependendo do contexto qualquer função ou método é um objeto em qualquer linguagem. Mas ok, entendi de qual contexto está falando.

Eu sempre falo que as pessoas ficaram tão obcecadas por OOP que todo mundo tem que dizer que a linguagem é OO. E um marketing frequentemente usado é dizer que tudo é objeto, e os objetos precisam ser de [primeira classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227485/101).

É possível, mas complicado, fazer código ser um objeto. No mínimo a performance será bem ruim.

Ruby não faz o método ser um objeto, mas possui uma representação do método que é um objeto, então fala-se assim, grosso modo. Isto por si só traz algumas desvantagens para a linguagem, mas também traz flexibilidade. Pense em ter uma classe de reflexão que te dá as informações do método, é isto, o objeto da representação é um objeto, não o método em si.

Posso estar enganado, mas pelo que entendi `Method` é para os métodos declarados e `Proc` é para os anônimos já que é uma estrutura de [*closure*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101) e este sim é um objeto e obrigatório para a *lambda* funcionar o mecanismo. O `Method` só é necessário em casos de [reflexão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13089/101) ou mecanismos parecidos.