# Parametrizar funções para receber funções

Tags: funções, dart, função-anônima

Quais as vantagens de parametrizar funções em Dart?

```
void main() {
  metodoSemFuncao();
  metodoComFuncao(funcao);  

}

void metodoSemFuncao(){
   funcao();
}

void metodoComFuncao(Function func){
    func();  
}

void funcao(){
  print("Botão Criado!");
}
```

Saída:

```
Botão Criado!
Botão Criado!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mesmas de qualquer linguagem :P

Primeiro estamos falando de criar um parâmetro e funções típicas são todas parametrizadas para ter mais relevância. Geralmente uma função deve executar algo com uma informação faltante que ela desconhece de antemão, ela receberá esta informação e fará algo com ela. Quando uma função recebe zero parâmetros ela pode fazer algo muito limitado e em geral ela só está sendo usada para controle de fluxo, ou seja, é só uma forma de evitar um `goto`, e chega ser até sacanagem chamá-la de função.

Note que em linguagens orientadas a objeto há uma parâmetro implícito nos métodos chamado `this` (Dart) ou `self`, então mesmo que não veja ele na assinatura do método ele está lá.

A outra coisa que estamos falando na pergunta é o uso da [função anônima](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13364/101), ou seja, um objeto que "guarda uma função" (na verdade ele guarda uma referência para uma função). Então, como quase toda linguagem Dart tem funções de [primeira classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227485/101) e o tipo deste objeto claramente é `Function`.

Este tipo de objeto é usado como mecanismo de [*callback*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/101).

No caso está misturando as duas coisas, então tem um objeto que "é uma função" e um parâmetro. Desta forma você pode parametrizar uma execução de código. O exemplo apresentado não mostra isso muito bem, mas assim fica melhor:

```
void metodoComFuncao(List<int> lista, Function func) {
    for (var i = 0; i < lista.lenght; i++) if (lista[i] % 2 == 0) func();  
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Dart/ParameterFunction.dart).

Aí chama:

```
metodoComFuncao(lista, funcao)
```

Note que não usa os parenteses em `funcao`, se usar ele chamará a função ali na hora e o seu resultado é que seria passado como argumento, o que no caso daria erro porque o resultado é um `void` e é esperado um objeto do tipo `Function`.

Desta forma você está executando algo dentro desta função que não importa para você o que é, é detalhe de implementação, mas você sabe que em determinado momento você quer que ela faça alguma coisa que você definiu em algum lugar, no caso a função `funcao()`. Se quiser outra coisa para executar passará outra função que executará outra coisa.

Também é possível usar uma sintaxe de *lambda* e nem criar uma função separada, você já cria e passa a função ali no argumento.

Então você cria melhores abstrações, isolando algo que é comum de se fazer mas o que fazer com completa exatidão você ainda não sabe, falta uma parte, você tem que "preencher a parte sublinhada", que é justamente o que o parâmetro te entrega, só que neste caso em vez de colocar nesta parte faltante um número ou um texto como é mais comum você coloca uma função que será executada e possivelmente dará um resultado (neste exemplo ela só executa mesmo, o que é mais raro).

Algumas pessoas acham isto tão sensacional que começam se lambuzar :)