# Uma classe é uma instância?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, classes, terminologia, independente-de-linguagem

Considerando o exemplo, pode-se afirmar que `p1` é uma instância de `Pessoa`, que é a classe:

```rb
class Pessoa
end

p1 = Pessoa.new()
# => #<Pessoa:0x00000001268ee528>
```

No entanto, não costuma-se dizer que `Pessoa`, a classe no exemplo anterior, também é uma instância. Tomando novamente como exemplo o Ruby, veja de que classe é `Pessoa`:

```rb
Pessoa.class
# => Class
```

Posso afirmar que `Pessoa` é uma instância de `Class`? Embora tenha usado Ruby para exemplificar, independente de linguagem, uma classe é sempre uma instância de algo que define o que são classes de forma mais genérica?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De forma genérica, não é. [Qual a diferença entre uma classe e um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/101). Objeto no caso é a instância.

Só para deixar algo claro antes:

`p1` é uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101). Ela tem um valor, então é um objeto que tem lá, é a instância de alguma coisa. Não precisa ser de uma classe. E de fato em quase todas as linguagens que definem uma classe ela modela um objeto que será armazenado por referência, portanto o que tem em `p1` é uma instância de um ponteiro para uma instância de outro objeto, no caso modelado pela classe `Pessoa`. Essa é a definição correta e deve ser entendida quando se quer aprender o certo. Informalmente falamos que o objeto está em `p1`, mas ele não está.

Entendido isso eu acho que a pergunta é sobre Ruby, o demonstrado no código não existe em outras linguagens. Inclusive boa parte do que mostra, o que explicaria o que está posto, é algo não só de Ruby, mas desta implementação da linguagem.

Ruby usa um conceito de metaclasses, então uma classe pode ser uma instância de uma metaclasse (note a diferença que ela não é uma classe normal). Instância de uma classe é um objeto, instância de uma metaclasse pode ser uma classe. Apesar do nome ser "instância" nos dois casos são coisas diferentes. Embora possa-se dizer que uma classe em Ruby não deixa de ser um objeto pela filosofia da linguagem de objetos serem [cidadãos de primeira classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227485/101).

Novamente, isso é algo de Ruby e uma ou outra linguagem. Não se aplica à maioria das linguagens orientadas a objeto (sem falar nas que sequer usam classes).

Então para deixar a resposta genérica, as linguagens que não tratam classes como se fossem objetos e não possuem metaclasses, classes não são instâncias de nada.

Em Ruby o uso correto da terminologia é dizer que `Pessoa` é uma instância de `Class`, está na [documentação](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Class.html). Não sei como usam informalmente.

Minha opinião é que Ruby está mais próximo de JavaScript, ou seja, tem classes, mas no fundo são protótipos, então você tem objetos que são usados como **base** para outras coisas, inclusive para outras classes, que não deixam de ser objetos. Não são exatamente modelos porque isso ocorre em classe real.

É importante separar o correto do que usamos informalmente no dia-a-dia. Dá para entender o informal, mas ele pode explicar errado para os desavisados.

Answer (score 0):

A classe é a receita e a instancia é o bolo.

Abaixo a representação de uma classe ( apenas a estrutura ) que contém o atributo nome ( também parte da estrutura )
Até momento temos só a estrutura e não temos nenhuma instancia/criação do uso dela na memória.

```
class Pessoa{
    nome;
}
```

Abaixo criamos duas instancias da estrutura/classe acima.

```
Pessoa p1 = new Pessoa(); // colocando uma instancia da classe pessoa na memória
Pessoa p2 = new Pessoa(); // colocando OUTRA instancia da classe pessoa na 

p1.nome = "nome A";
p2.nome = "nome B";
```

Vemos então que p1 e p2 tem a mesma estrutura os mesmos atributos. porém são duas instancias diferentes da classe pessoa. até adicionamos valores diferentes para as instancias.

Comment: Ele está falando da classe ser uma instância e não objeto, que sempre é.