# É possível vincular uma string ao nome de uma nova instancia em C#?

Tags: c#, array, .net, string

Usando C#, gostaria que o valor de uma *string* fosse utilizado (ou vinculado) ao nome de uma nova instancia de um objeto. No caso do exemplo abaixo onde há **XXX** gostaria que recebesse o valor da *string* `NumeroDaConta`.

---

```
namespace ConsoleApp9

{

    public class Conta
    {
        public string Nome;
        public int Teste; 
    }
}
```

---

```
using ConsoleApp9;
    
    
Console.WriteLine("Digite um numero");
    
public int Count = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    
public string NumeroDaConta = "Conta " + Count.ToString();
    
public Conta XXX = new Conta();
```

Comment: as variáveis são declaradas antes de se instanciar, antes do código ser compilado, então não é possível fazer algo assim, e ainda assim, imagina que precisa usar a variável XXX abaixo, o programa precisa saber exatamente o nome da variável antes de usar. Por curiosidade, para que precisa fazer isso? explique melhor a necessidade, talvez um dicionário te ajude mas é preciso entender melhor o que pretende

Comment: Muito obrigado cara. Na verdade, queria criar um laço de "while" e ir adicionando instancias com o nome incrementado a partir dessa string. Por exemplo, enquanto o usuário fosse digitando o número um novo objeto do tipo Contaé criado (Conta 1, Conta 2, Conta 3...)

Comment: mas pra que vai fazer isso não após instanciar quando o programa estiver sendo executado não vai poder ver os nomes? Pooderia por exemplo fazer assim : `var contas = new List<Conta>()` e ir adicionando: `contas.Add(new Conta())`, mas isso é só para exemplificar.. já um dicionário poderia identicar com um nome, assim por exemplo: `var contas = new Dictionary<string, Conta>()` e a seguir: `contas.Add("NumeroDaConta", new Conta());`, talvez isso ajude a entender, mas ainda assim não me parece uma boa ideia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível, mas não é adequado fazer isso. E em geral você não precisa disto. Cada conta criada virará uma variável no código?

Bem, vamos conceituar melhor as coisas. Tem diversos erros nesse código, mas não vou falar sobre eles porque não é foco da pergunta, só recomendo procurar por melhores fontes ou outro método para aprender, se treinar o erro é ele que fará para sempre.

Uma instância não tem nome no código. Nome para indicar um local na memória onde tem um [objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205482/101) (uma [instância](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/514777/101)), de forma direta ou por [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101), é chamado de [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) ([mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/338603/101)). E é isso que parece querer usar no lugar do XXX.

Se o problema pedir por isso mesmo então é possível até ter várias variáveis existindo na execução do programa, mas não expressadas individualmente no código, e sim durante a execução. Essas variáveis são consideradas indexáveis e o *array* é a forma mais simples e famosa de fazer isto (embora seja mais provável que uma [`List`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) seja melhor opção).

Outra forma muito utilizada, mas menos falada é o dicionário, que pode ser usado de diversas formas, sendo a mais comum no .NET o [`Dictionary`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). A diferença é justamente que o índice é uma *string* (pode ser outros tipos, mas `string` é o mais comum). É exatamente o que deseja. Parece.

Isso pode não ser uma boa solução, para funcionar corretamente terá que ter muitos cuidados, qualquer mínimo erro no uso da aplicação e não obterá o resultado esperado. Índices assim são ruins, especialmente quando é controlado pelo usuário e não pelo programador. O programador pode ajudar dar menos problemas ou pelo menos detetá-los, mas dá trabalho e é fácil esquecer de algo possível, usuário precisa ser estudado pela NASA.

Códigos e números existem no mundo, não é nem só na programação para evitar esse erro. A lista seria bem mais útil com eles, e só porque é um experimento, não entenda que isso é um código real que poderá ser usado em aplicação em produção. Se os códigos podem ser esparsos o dicionário ainda pode ser útil, já que um *array* ou lista precisa de uma sequência contínua, mas já é melhor que um texto.

Número da conta deveria ser uma *string* ou um número? O usuário escolhe o número que bem entender, do jeito que quiser? Experimenta digitar uma letra quando pede um número. Percebe como tem muitos erros conceituais? Números de conta costumam ser sequenciais, ainda que a pessoa possa escolher um deles.

As outras formas ([reflexão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/506768/101), injeção de código usando o [Roslyn](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82756/101)) são bem mais complicadas, ineficientes e "erradas", mesmo que funcione.

Escolha fugir da pseudo qualificação.