# Qual a diferença entre inicializador e construtor em programação orientada a objetos?

Tags: c#, .net, construtor, instanciar-objeto, inicialização

Estive lendo um livro de programação e me deparei com o termo inicializador. Ainda sou novo com programação orientada a objetos. Basicamente, a linha de código traz isso:
´´´

```
man = new Guy(){Cash = 50, Name = "Joe"};
```

Sendo `Guy` uma classe previamente criada e `man` um novo objeto criado dessa classe. Pelo que entendi, o inicializador garante que o objeto comece com valores iniciais, mas o construtor também não serve para isso? O que eu entendo é que o construtor é um método com o mesmo nome da classe com o objetivo de inicializar os valores. Qual seria a diferença entre os dois?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O contrutor é o método que cria uma instância de uma classe. Como tal, ele pode demandar parâmetros para já te devolver uma classe pronta, mas ele faz mais que isso e é diferente de um inicializador.

Um inicializador nada mais é que uma forma de já te devolver o objeto com alguns valores setados. Mas uma coisa **muito** importante é, o inicializador só vai acessar os membros que forneçam acesso "externo" à classe, como propriedades `public` por exemplo.

Já o construtor pode ter acesso a tudo que existe na classe, como membros `private`.

Um exemplo para ilustrar:

```
public class Guy
{
    public int Cash { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Com esse código é possível usar o exemplo da sua pergunta, agora imagine que eu não queria quer "Name" seja inicializado, apenas setado na construção do objeto  e classe fosse assim:

```
public class Guy
{
    public Guy(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public int Cash { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

Nesse caso, o inicializador não poderia mudar o valor de "Name", isso só poderia ser feito no contrutor, por causa do  `private set`, podemos dizer que "externamente" ele é imutável, só pode ser difinido no construtor.

Note que, o construtor tem acesso a tudo na classe, mas o inicializador apenas ao que pode ser exposto.
Um outro exemplo para ilustrar mais:

```
public class Guy
{
    private int age;

    public Guy(int age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int Cash { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int GetAge()
    {
        return this.age;
    }
}
```

Nesse exemplo, o objeto seria construido assim:

```
var man = new Guy(20);
var idade = man.GetAge();
```

E nunca poderia ser inicializado "age" assim:

```
new Guy(){ age = 20 }
```

Para finalizar um exemplo mais do mundo real: a classe Guy precisa receber por **injeção de dependência** um serviço. Isso porque, os mecanismos de injeção de dependência "injetam" diretamente na construção da classe, ou seja, é algo que classe precisa para trabalhar mas não necessariamente ela precisa explor, logo não pode ser inicializado:

```
public class Guy
{
    private readonly IServicoDeTransforcao _servico;

    public Guy(IServicoDeTransforcao servico)
    {
        this._servico = servico;
    }

    public int Cash { get; set; }

    public string Name { get;  set; }

    public Girl Transform()
    {
        return this._servico.Transform(this.Cash, this.Name);
    }
}
```

Note que aqui somente o construtor recebe o "servico" como parâmetro, ele não pode ser inicializado, até porque, a classe precisa disso "pronto" na construção, e não quer expor o servico, é para uso interno, então não faz sentido ser inicializado.

Um último ponto importate, seguindo a documentação aqui: [How to initialize objects by using an object initializer](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-BR/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer), para inicializar o construtor sem parâmetros da classe não deve ser `private`:

> O compilador processa inicializadores de objeto acessando primeiro o
> construtor de instância sem parâmetros e, em seguida, processando as
> inicializações de membro. Portanto, se o construtor sem parâmetros for
> declarado como private na classe, os inicializadores de objeto que
> exigem acesso público falharão.

Espero que possa perceber a diferença do construtor e do inicializador, que é bem mais restrito.

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas dos dois. Só para resumir, tanto o construtor quanto o inicializador podem ser usados para inicializar valores na instância criada, a principal diferença é o nível de acesso que cada um possui. Estou certo ?

Comment: Ola @GabrielOliveira,  essa talvez seja mesmo a principal diferença, pensando em inicializar um objeto :)

Answer (score 6):

Vamos começar com as definições:

[Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101) (não vou demonstrar aqui tudo o que já foi feito na resposta original, lá está mais detalhado).

[Sobre o inicializador de objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126348/101).

`man` é uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) (provavelmente [de acordo com o modelo da classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/338603/101), [mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96710/101)) e não um [objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205482/101), você está criando um objeto ali para guardar na variável, [instanciando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/514777/101) a classe `Guy`.

Logo após fazer a construção sem inicializar nada na classe, ou seja, esse construtor não parece fazer muito sentido já que ele deixa isto acontecer.

Em C# mais moderno poderia até escrever apenas:

```
man = new {Cash = 50, Name = "Joe"};
```

considerando que `man` é do tipo `Guy`.

O seu código e este aqui estão chamando o [construtor padrão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34685/101), sem parâmetros. Apenas aqui fica mais implícito já que ele não tem serventia nesse caso.

Cada vez mais veremos esse tipo de sintaxe sem a chamada explícita do construtor com as modernidades de C# 9, 10, 11 e quem sabe outras.

Depois tem o inicializador que é apenas um *syntax sugar* para iniciar as variáveis membros do objeto.

Seria o mesmo que escrever:

```
man = new Guy();
man.Cash = 50;
man.Name = "Joe";
```

Mas é garantido que seja feito tudo de uma vez (pode lançar exceção, mas não vou entrar nisso).

Com as novas semânticas das novas versões algumas situações podem ter uma [restrição de alteração de valor a não ser no inicialização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/539114/101) ([ver mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156804/101)).

O inicializador de objeto não garante nada nas versões antigas do C# porque ele não era obrigado ser chamado. Para resolver isso sempre existiu construtor e usado corretamente pode garantir algo. É possível garantir até mesmo com o construtor padrão, se quiser apenas valores padrões declarados na classe, já mencionado antes nos *links*.

Nas versões atuais o inicializador pode ser obrigado dependendo de como o tipo é declarado.

Então o construtor te dá mais garantias que o inicializador, permite definir ordem das coisas, validar e manipular vários valores em conjunto e não apenas individualmente. O construtor pode dar mais liberdade, flexibilidade e poder que o inicializador.

O inicializador pode tornar as coisas mais bonitinhas e óbvias.

Na prática ambos podem entregar o mesmo de jeitos diferentes, em alguns casos é questão de estilo escolher um ou outro. A definição ocorre mais em função da declaração da classe do que a instanciação do objeto. Para todos os efeitos a inicialização funciona como uma construção mais limitada, mas nem tanto.

Por exemplo, pode injetar dependência no inicializador, sem construtor, aí você decide se fica mais ou menos conveniente. Se não tiver um algoritmo sofisticado demais a inicialização pode fazer o que o construtor pode. E nas versões mais recentes de C# de forma bem conveniente. Exemplo pegando da resposta do Pontual:

```
public class Guy {
    public IServicoDeTransforcao Servico { private get; init; }
    public int Cash { get; set; }
    public string Name { get;  set; }

}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/InitializerNoConstructor.cs).

No código, depois de inicializado só pode acessar o serviço internamente para pegar o dado, fora nem pegar pode, muito menos alterar, que não pode nem dentro da classe.

O outro exemplo da resposta dele também cai na mesma questão, e de qualquer forma aquilo tem código estilo Java e não C# que prefere propriedades sempre. Como a linguagem é mais poderosa ela permite códigos melhores do que Java, e melhores até que ela permitia antes.

Não vou entrar na questão completa que tem casos que o construtor ainda é importante porque está explicado no primeiro *link*.

Então cuidado com material ultrapassado, a linguagem vai evoluindo e vai permitindo coisas que antes não eram possíveis. Se você aprender o antigo terá dificuldade de usar o novo, sendo que o novo já está aí. Você teve a chance de aprender o novo mas ficou com o antigo por usar material que agora é ruim.

- [Pode ser útil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101).
- [Também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/481890/101).
- [Mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124742/101).
- [Vai te ajudar e tem mais *links*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/324099/101).
- [E ainda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/101).

Comment: *"O outro exemplo da resposta dele também cai na mesma questão, e de qualquer forma aquilo é código Java e não C# ..."* se estiver se referindo a minha resposta sugiro que reavalie o texto da sua resposta, pq não há nada de Java lá (não há `{get; set;}` em Java por exemplo), apenas um exemplo simples para ilustrar, não que seja relevante mas eu sequer programo em java :)

Comment: `GetAge()` é Java, não C#.

Comment: isso é simplesmente um método para demonstrar que não é possível inicializar um valor que é passado no construtor e é setado como private... se acha que é java, tente compilar esse condigo como java...  só pq java usa "Get" eu não posso usar num exemplo? fora que java usaria `getAge()` e não `GetAge`... agradecia se parasse de assumir coisas nas minha resposta e referenciando na sua, se houver alguma duvida use a area de comentários, ela serve para isso, obrigado

Comment: https://ideone.com/ml2FJ5 Quando você dá um exemplo ruim para leigos, e faz muito nas suas respostas, você incentiva as pessoas aprenderem errado, lamento que goste disso. Só porque você aprendeu assim não significa que seja uma boa ideia. Eu agradeceria que você fosse menos teimoso, mas eu já sei que não acontecerá. Aí parará de assumir coisas em muitas situações e não reclamará de cosias que você faz.

Comment: assim é fácil, editou o código..., coloca o código como está, com o código completo e as properties get/set e compila em java... o sr que é teimoso,  mas não vou discutir com quem sempre quer ter razão, boa sorte

Comment: Não editei nada, tirei a parte irrelevante, não Java. Releia o texto: `aquilo é código Java e não C# que prefere propriedades sempre`. Vou facilitar para você: Se C# prefere **propriedade**, eu não estou falando da parte da propriedade, eu estou falando da parte que não é propriedade. É lógica básica e simples. Então eu compilei a parte que eu estou falando no texto, eu não vou tentar compilar a parte que eu excluo no meu texto. Quando você tiver razão você volta aqui, para isso precisa entender do que está falando. Não faça projeção. Novamente assumiu coisas e acha o oposto.

Answer (score 0):

Em C#, você pode inicializar variáveis de classe de duas maneiras: usando inicializadores de propriedade ou no construtor da classe. Ambos os métodos têm suas próprias finalidades e diferenças.

Inicializador de Propriedade-
Sintaxe:

public class MinhaClasse
{
public int MinhaVariavel { get; set; } = 10;
}

Características:
O valor é definido diretamente na declaração da propriedade.
Pode ser usado apenas para propriedades autoimplementadas.

Construtor-
Sintaxe:

public class MinhaClasse
{
public int MinhaVariavel { get; set; }

```
public MinhaClasse()
{
    MinhaVariavel = 10;
}
```

}

Características:
O valor é definido no corpo do construtor.
Pode ser usado para qualquer tipo de propriedade, incluindo aquelas que exigem lógica personalizada na inicialização.
Diferenças:

Momento de Execução:
O inicializador de propriedade é avaliado no momento da criação da instância, enquanto o construtor é chamado depois que a instância é criada.

Lógica Adicional:
Se você precisar de lógica adicional ao inicializar uma propriedade, use um construtor. O construtor permite uma maior flexibilidade na execução de código durante a inicialização.

Acesso a Parâmetros:
O construtor pode aceitar parâmetros, permitindo uma personalização mais avançada na inicialização, enquanto o inicializador de propriedade não aceita parâmetros.

Compatibilidade:
O inicializador de propriedade está disponível apenas no C# 6.0 e versões posteriores, enquanto os construtores sempre estiveram presentes.

Escolher entre um inicializador de propriedade e um construtor depende da complexidade da lógica de inicialização que você precisa e da versão do C# que está utilizando. Em alguns casos, ambos podem ser usados em conjunto para fornecer uma inicialização flexível e concisa.

Comment: `O inicializador de propriedade é avaliado no momento da criação da instância, enquanto o construtor é chamado depois que a instância é criada` Tem referência disto? Porque até onde eu sei a inicialização da propriedade é *syntax sugar* para jogar no construtor. Conhece o `intit`?