# Comparando endereços de memória em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, objetos, operadores, comparação

Realizando uma comparação entre **endereços de memória** usando o constructor `new Date()`, como a comparação está sendo feito pelo mesmo construtor, não entendo porque retorna `false`. Sendo que ao comparar o mesmo endereço de memória era pra retornar verdadeiro.

```js
const d1 = new Date(0);
const d2 = new Date(0);
console.log("09)", d1 === d2)
```

Comment: O que `new Date` retorna é um objeto (a instância criada a partir da instanciação da "classe" `Date`). Em JavaScript, quando se compara dois objetos, tem-se comparação por referência. No seu exemplo, como se trata de dois objetos _diferentes_, as referências não são iguais. Portanto, retorna-se `false`. P.S. em JavaScript, não há, num alto nível, a noção de endereço de memória, já que a linguagem abstrai isso como um detalhe de implementação.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu concordo que o ideal seria retornar `true`.

O texto da pergunta é bastante confuso e quer que algo seja verdadeiro, mesmo sem ser. É como dizer "eu ando e tudo parece plano, não sinto a inclinação do terreno, portanto a Terra é plana".

Em sua defesa tenho que dizer que JavaScript fez algo bem confuso com isso (não só isso).

Também está certo na ideia de comparação de endereços de memória, é isto que está fazendo. Se você cria dois objetos na memória, cada um ocupa um lugar diferente, então eles possuem endereços diferentes. Como comparar esses endereços e querer que eles sejam iguais, portanto dar `true` nessa tentativa? Essa é a parte que menos faz sentido. Basta tirar essa ideia equivocada da cabeça.

> Sendo que ao comparar o mesmo endereço de memória era pra retornar verdadeiro

Não é o mesmo endereço, simples assim.

> a comparação está sendo feito pelo mesmo construtor

Isso não faz sentido algum, isso não existe. Talvez queria dizer "a comparação está sendo feita com objetos que foram criados com o mesmo valor no construtor".

Se a dúvida fosse porque comparar dois objetos que são números simples dá `true` para a igualdade e com o `Date` isto não acontece, faria mais sentido. E a resposta já está na pergunta. O `Date` é um objeto por referência, e falar em endereços na pergunta mostra que sabe disto.

Um tipo que tem semântica de valor compara seu valor e não o endereço onde o valor está, então aí o mesmo conteúdo deveria dar igual, mesmo que os objetos estejam em endereços diferentes.

Eu odeio a ideia de comparar objetos pelo seu endereço, isso é errado (pode ter esse mecanismo como algo secundário para algo específico, mas não o padrão). Java errou nisso deixando os tipos por referência comparar pelo endereço da referência e não pelo seu valor. A maioria das linguagens erram, segundo minha opinião, porque permitem que os tipos sejam assim, ainda que permitam que não sejam e alguns dos tipos padrões seguem a semântica de valor, especialmente no tipo `string` que é fonte de confusão porque ele quase sempre é um tipo por referência, mas semântica de valor. Em Java nem `String`, nem `Date` são comparados por valor usando o operador de igualdade.

Curiosamente JavaScript acertou em dar a semântica correta para o tipo `String` comparando por valor e não por referência, mesmo o tipo sendo assim. Mas por que diabos o `Date`, que é muito mais um tipo por valor, ainda que seja criado como referência, não tem essa comparação?

Aí você pergunta para o Brendan Eich que criou a linguagem. E a resposta provavelmente será algo como "eu tinha dois meses pra entregar, não deu muito para pensar nisso, saiu assim e não deu mais para arrumar depois quando começaram aparecer programadores para usá-la" (no começo programadores sérios não usavam JS, demorou para perceberem o erro).

Então a confusão da linguagem é essa, em um tipo muito mais óbvio que a comparação deveria ser pelo seu valor, mas não é assim, compara pelo endereço.

Eu adoraria mostrar para você que os endereços de memória são diferentes, mas não há como pegar o endereço de um objeto, a linguagem achou melhor não ter essa possibilidade, então acredite em mim, as variáveis `d1` e `d2` tem endereços diferentes armazenados nela. E por ser um objeto por referência o valor dos objetos referenciados por essas variáveis podem ser iguais ou não, tanto faz.

Aí se você poderia usar a lógica e pensar que se não pode pegar o endereço da memória como ele compara os endereços? Sim, isso é outra confusão da linguagem, a linguagem faz isso mesmo sendo uma exceção à regra.

Por isso que eu questiono que JS seja uma linguagem fácil, linguagens fáceis não possuem exceções, pelo menos não para coisas sem necessidade. Ela teve a enorme oportunidade de ter só comparações por valor. Ou deveria assumir que endereços de memória existem e devem ser usados em qualquer situação, ou seja, serem de [primeira classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227485/101).

Em todas as tecnologias deve usar um mecanismo depois de ler a documentação, porque se está documentado (mesmo sendo maluco), poderá usar de forma adequada e entender essas maluquices que escolheram fazer. Não use `Date` sem dominar tudo que [está lá na doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

A parte boa é que em uma versão futura poderá ter uma API melhor de tempo e podem resolver isso, ainda que não possam resolver todos os códigos que usam e vão continuar usando a API antiga. Quase todas as linguagens têm uma API de tempo errada e precisam ou precisaram ser melhoradas.

Por sorte tem uma forma de comparar por valor, e aí daria `true`. Você pode pegar um valor numérico simples vindo da data e fazer a comparação por valor. Execute e veja:

```js
var d1 = new Date(0);
var d2 = new Date(0);
console.log(d1 == d2);
console.log(d1 === d2);
console.log(d1 != d2);
console.log(d1 !== d2);
console.log(new Date(1) > new Date(0));
console.log(d1.getTime() === d2.getTime());
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Operators/CompareDate.js).

Notou uma coisa pior? Quando compara se é maior (ou menor) aí ele dá a resposta por valor? Então eu te pergunto: por que as pessoas gostam dessa linguagem tão doida?

É sempre bom questionar, principalmente quando parece estar tudo certo, até porque o que parece certo pode estar errado e só parecer, por exemplo que a Terra parece plana. Esse exemplo por sorte deu errado e obrigou a questionar. Não conte com a sorte.