# Qual é o objetivo do "data class"?

Tags: kotlin, data-class

No Kotlin é possível criar uma classe da seguinte forma:

```
data class Dragon(private val name: String, val glass: Int)
```

Qual é o principal objetivo do `data class` no Kotlin? Quando devemos usar?

Comment: Quem negativou a pergunta poderia pelo menos explicar o motivo para que eu possa edita-la e tentar colaborar mais com nossa comunidade.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Também chamado de [registro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_(computer_science)), é para ser uma estrutura simples basicamente com dados, sem comportamentos, a não ser os necessários para a infraestrutura básica da linguagem, como comparação (`equals()`), *hash* (`hashCode()`), métodos acessores para os campos definidos (compatíveis com Java Beans), cópia (`copy()`) e *stringificação* (`toString()`), além do construtor, claro. Então costumamos dizer que ela é POD (Plain Old Data).

Não é possível herdar de classes de dados. A sintaxe é bastante simplificada:

```
data class User(val name: String, val age: Int)
```

Seria mais ou menos o mesmo que fazer em Java:

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public User() {
        this.name = "";
        this.age = 0;
    }

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = 0;
    }

    public User(int age) {
        this.name = "";
        this.age = age;
    }

    public User(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String component1() { //para acesso posicional e deconstrução
        return name;
    }

    public int component2() {
        return age;
    }

    public User copy() {
        return new User(name, age);
    }

    public User copy(String newName) {
        return new User(newName, age);
    }

    public User copy(int newAge) {
        return new User(name, newAge);
    }

    public User copy(String newName, int newAge) {
        return new User(newName, newAge);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        User user = (User) o;

        if (age != user.age) return false;
        return name != null ? name.equals(user.name) : user.name == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + age;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Kotlin/DataClass.kt).

Não é uma maravilha? Está previsto isto em C#, só não se sabe quando, era para ter desde a versão 6. Em C# é mais complexo ainda.

[É possível ter comportamentos extras na classe e pode estender (não no sentido de herança) como uma classe normal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/228429/101).

[Documentação](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html).

Veja mais em [Qual e a diferenca entre Kotlin data class e Scala case class?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/139839/101).

Comment: Se declaradas como `var` teria os `setter` certo?!

Comment: Sim, o data classe pode ser imutável, mas com o uso de `var` em vez de `val` ele pode ser mutável.

Comment: @acklay sim, estava vendo agora mais detalhes e é possível neste caso.

Comment: Uma razão que eu encontrava para as *data class* serem finais era o facto dos métodos `equals()`e `toString()` ficarem "errados". No entanto, ao permitir que sejam estendidas acontece o mesmo.

Comment: @ramaral defina "errado"

Comment: Com essa pergunta você me obrigou a pensar melhor e de facto no caso de serem estendidas os métodos não ficam "errados" tendo em conta que eles apenas consideram as propriedades resultantes das variáveis declaradas no construtor. No caso de herdadas, ai sim, se a classe filha declarasse mais variáveis no seu construtor, elas não seriam consideradas naqueles métodos.

Comment: @ramaral mas em `data class` não tem herança.

Comment: Sim, talvez uma das razões(não sei se haverá outras) para não permitir herança seja garantir que os métodos criados automaticamente não fiquem "errados"(usem todas as variáveis declaradas no construtor). Eu estava errado quando afirmei que isso acontecia no caso da classe ser estendida.

Comment: Soa como structs.

Comment: @felipsmartins Mas é classe mesmo :)