# Numa data class é possível ter outras propriedades além das geradas automaticamente?

Tags: propriedade, kotlin, data-class

O Kotlin permite simplificar a criação do que em Java chamamos de POJO:

```
data class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String)
```

Com isso obtemos uma classe com os *getter* para todas a variáveis declaradas no construtor bem como os métodos `equals()`, `toString()`, `copy()`, entre outros.

A minha dúvida é se é possível adicionar outras propriedades. Por exemplo na classe `Person` acrescentar/declarar a propriedade `fullName: String`.

Comment: Acrescentar novas propriedades? Como pensaria fazer isso? Nela mesmo? Não é só mudar o fonte? Claro que pode ter problemas se ela já foi usada em algum código, como em qualquer classe. Criar uma nova baseada nesta não pode. O que eu estou tentando ver se dá para colocar comportamentos não padrões nela.

Comment: @bigown Não pensei, a premissa era a linguagem permitir. E através de Extension Properties é possível?

Comment: Entendi, preciso descobrir.

Comment: @ramaral, você também pode criar propriedades que são originadas de outras, seja por delegação ou até mesmo em tempo de contrução.

Comment: @Wakim Pode exemplificar como?

Comment: Deve ser a 98ª vez que essa mesmíssima pergunta chega à front-page com título e conteúdo alterados. Que está acontecendo? Nem precisa dizer!

Comment: @TonyMontana pode explicar onde quer chegar? O título nuca foi alterado e as **duas** alterações foram mínimas. A primeira, focar a pergunta apenas na adição de propriedades(POJO por definição não tem comportamento), a segunda, torná-la coerente com o código(com `val` não é gerado setter).

Comment: Pelo que eu vejo a resposta certa ainda não apareceu hehe. O que responde a pergunta do @ramaral é que data class é uma classe como outra qualquer, com algumas poucas restrições. Todas as outras, inclusive a minha não abordam isso, falam de extensões e propriedades geradas sobre outras. Se for o caso, seria melhor ter uma resposta com esse conteúdo.

Comment: @Wakim Você tem razão. Julgo que a única restrição é não poder ser herdada. Pelo que me apercebi é possível pegar numa classe qualquer, que você já tenha, colocar a *keyword data* e tudo funciona, recebendo de "borla" os referidos métodos automáticos. Posso estar errado e peço desculpa se estiver mas o que aconteceu foi que as respostas originalmente foram um pouco precipitadas e com alguma falta de conhecimento. Elas foram atrás de eu ter referido a possibilidade de usar  *Extension Properties*, no entanto a do bigown já se aproxima disso. Sugiro que edite a sua resposta nesse sentido.

Comment: @Wakim Note que o bigown refere, em um [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/228429/%c3%89-poss%c3%advel-customizar-uma-data-class#comment467878_228447), que "isto está sendo excelente aprendizado"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível criar extensões de propriedade, e no exemplo citado deve dar certo porque acredito que no fundo não é uma propriedade, pra falar a verdade nem gosto muito do nome, porque eu acho que propriedade implica em ter um campo de estado vinculado, o que não é muito o caso. Então pode criar um método *getter* e até um *setter* dependendo do que quer fazer e a sintaxe de uso será igual ao de um campo, mas não pode ter um campo de estado associado, então a resposta é sim para o comportamento e não para o estado.

É possível adicionar comportamentos e até estados extras na própria `data class` também, mas eles não farão parte da estrutura básica da classe, por exemplo uma propriedade que não está no construtor primário não entra no `equals()`, ou `toString()`.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val pessoa = Person("João", "Silva")
    pessoa.age = 47
    println(pessoa.fullName)
    println(pessoa.Firula())
    println(pessoa.firula)
    val pessoa2 = pessoa.copy()
    println(pessoa2.age)
    pessoa2.age = 40
    println(pessoa2.age)
    println(pessoa == pessoa2)
    println(pessoa2)
}

data class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String) {
    fun Firula(): String = "O nome dele é " + firstName + " " + lastName
    val firula: String
        get() = "O nome dele é " + firstName + " " + lastName
    var age: Int = 0
    override fun toString() = firstName + " " + lastName
}

val Person.fullName: String
    get() = firstName + " " + lastName
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/RSesh6). E [no **Kotlin Play**](https://pl.kotl.in/_3PwyQYb5). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Kotlin/ExtendDataClass.kt).

Claro que é possível estender com funções também que só tem comportamento.

Só note que a extensão ocorre estaticamente, não tem nada de herança nessa extensão. Então são apenas facilitadores, não muda a estrutura da classe, seja uma classe de dados ou uma classe normal.

Comment: Então, é possível adicionar funções mas não propriedades?

Comment: Então, é possível adicionar propriedade que não são bem propriedades :) Pra mim esse tipo de propriedade é só uma função por não ter estado, mas a sintaxe de acesso é de uma propriedade. Acho uma terminologia confusa porque existem dois tipos de propriedades, uma com estado e outra sem estado. Há uma semântica diferente entre elas e acho quase uma sacanagem ter o mesmo nome.

Comment: Você está a referir-se às extensões de propriedade?

Comment: Também vamos analisar o que é o termo *adicionar* que usou. Se for na própria *data class* acho que dá para adicionar ambos, porque a propriedade sem estado é uma função ou par de funções. Posso verificar se dá tudo e acho que até dá (precisaria confirmar), é claro que que se você criar uma propriedade com estado dentro da classe de dados ela não seria incluso nos métodos gerados automaticamente. Pelo menos a intuição diz isso.

Comment: Sim, a ideia era saber se era possível acrescentar à própria classe, no fundo como você fez com a função `Firula()`.

Comment: @ramaral até estava sim, mas tanto faz. O que tem de diferente na extensão é que ela nunca pode ter estado e dentro da classe pode ou não.

Comment: Sim eu isso sei, por isso ter desconfiado de que se estava a referir a elas.

Comment: Mudei o exemplo, acho que agora cubro todos itens, mas se não, me avise, isto está sendo excelente aprendizado e servirá para C# qdo tiver o mesmo. A única desgraça de Kotlin é que o compilador é lento que dói.

Comment: Agora está. No fundo a pergunta era se a declaração da *data class* se restringia àquela forma(talvez devesse reformulá-la). Pela sua resposta vejo que é permitido abrir parêntesis recto e declarar funções e propriedades como em qualquer classe.

Answer (score 4):

Sim, é possível. Uma forma de fazer isso é através [das extensões](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html).

Pode-se criar tanto funções como propriedades desta forma.

Para declarar uma extensão, é necessário prefixar seu nome com o tipo sendo estendido.

A *keyword* **`this`** é válida dentro de funções de extensão e é usada para se referir ao objeto "recebedor" (o que está estendido).

Propriedades de extensão não suportam o uso de [*backing fields*](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields).

Veja um exemplo completo

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val per = Person("Linq", "Bueno")
    println(per.obterFullName())
    println(per.fullName)
}

fun Person.obterFullName() = "${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}"
// ^ Isto é uma função de extensão

val Person.fullName: String
  get() = "${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}"
// ^ Isto é uma propriedade de extensão    

data class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String)
```

[Veja funcionando aqui.](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/vhouhs0nd0iec9q9oiqpi1lt2u/m8269eso5klbrjors4g02rbj74)

Answer (score 2):

Complementando as excelentes respostas, você pode criar propriedades imutáveis baseadas em outras existentes.

Seja na inicialização/declaração:

```
data class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String) {
    val fullName = "$firstName $lastName"
}
```

Se ainda fizer mais sentido por questão de organização (é claro que se a inicialização for pequena não precisamos usar o `init`):

```
data class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String) {
    val fullName: String

    init {
        fullName = "$firstName $lastName"
    }
}
```

Ou via lazy instantiation:

```
data class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String) {
    val fullName: String by lazy { "$firstName $lastName" }
}
```

Comment: Em vez de "na inicialização" não deveria ser "na declaração"?

Comment: Sim e não hehe. Aquele trecho de código é executado na inicialização da classe, mas ta na declaração mesmo.

Comment: Tem razão, a propriedade é declarada e inicializada ao mesmo tempo. Eu estava a pensar em termos da classe.