# O que é lazy instantiation?

Tags: propriedade, kotlin, lazy-loading

Vi aqui na [resposta do Wakim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/228475/35406) esse trecho de código:

> ```
> data class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String) { 
>     val fullName: String by lazy { "$firstName $lastName" } 
> }
> ```

O que é esse tal de *lazy instantiation*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Este é uma técnica de [memoização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104014/101). Então neste caso está declarando uma propriedade que possui um `get` que entregará o valor definido ali, no caso `"$firstName $lastName"`, porém o valor ali é gerado apenas uma vez e não precisa ser calculado todas as vezes que acessar a propriedade, o que em geral é um ganho de performance, ainda mais se a informação tiver que fazer um cálculo complexo ou pegar informação externa a aplicação.

O exemplo que a documentação mostra é

```
val lazyValue: String by lazy {
    println("computed!")
    "Hello"
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(lazyValue)
    println(lazyValue)
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ieC5dA). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hfvosqft-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Kotlin/LazyInstantaition.kt).

E o resultado é

> ```
> computed!
> Hello
> Hello
> ```

Que mostra que a função que gera o valor é executada apenas uma vez, mas continua produzindo o mesmo resultado. Isto é obtido através da infraestrutura já fornecida por [`<T> Lazy()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/lazy.html).

[Documentação](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html).

Comment: Achava que memoization é o ato de transformar algo em meme. huehuh

Comment: Aí é memeização :)