# Diferenças entre Java e Scala

Tags: java, scala

Quais as principais diferenças entre Java e Scala? Ambas tem estas similaridades:

- Ambas são orientada a objetos
- Ambas compilam para *bytecode* e rodam na JVM
- Ambas tem *lambdas* (Java 8)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rodar na JVM e compilar para *bytecode* são detalhes de implementação e não faz parte da característica da linguagem.

Há similaridades mais importantes, por exemplo o [paradigma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101) mais importante de Java é o imperativo e não o orientado a objetos. Já Scala usa o funcional o mais que pode. Imperativo e funcional são antagônicos, [orientação a objetos não](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13372/101) e por isso está presente em ambas. Mesmo assim é possível ter um pouco do imperativo e funcional juntos. Scala tem bastante, Java começou ter um pouco.

Hoje ambas possuem características funcionais. Scala já nasceu assim e força bastante este paradigma. Java vem adotando isso mais recentemente e ainda é tímido, um exemplo é o uso de *lambda*. Em Scala este recursos é melhor implementado. Quando a comparação é com Java mais moderno tem menos diferenças. Java decidiu que precisava se aproximar de Scala, na medida do possível. E as versões mais novas devem adotar mais características.

## Diferenças

- Scala é menos verbosa, um dos problemas que as pessoas mais reclamam do Java e de certa forma a maioria das outras diferenças é sobre isto. Por exemplo ela tem sobrecarga de operador, compreensões,
- Scala adota um modelo chamado Actor para trabalhar com concorrência.
- Scala adota técnicas mais funcionais como a imutabilidade por padrão, a transparência referencial e uma sintaxe mais apropriada para o funcional, como o *pattern matching*.
- A tipagem de Scala é mais segura e estrita. Ela possui tipos existenciais e tipos de alta ordem, além de controle de variância, melhor controle de valores opcionais (não tem `null`).
- Alguns tipos criados por Scala são mais adequados para utilização nela. Em geral podem acabar sendo usados em Java também com algumas vantagens.
- Scala abandonou a ideia de exceções checadas.
- Scala permite melhor composição e incentiva isso, por exemplo adotando [Traits](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/279252/101).
- Scala tem [*case class*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/139839/101).
- E macros.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Acho que vale por curiosidade histórica isto que vou comentar. Ainda na época do Java 6, houve uma grande profusão de linguagens compiladas para JVM (por padrão). E na época a JVM não ajudava em nada essas linguagens. Houve, então, um congresso de linguagens baseadas em JVM, e lá sugeriram o bytecode invokeDynamics, pois os lambdas eram um problema grande de performance. E foi mais ou menos assim que o invokeDynamics surgiu na JVM 7, mesmo não tendo lambda no Java 7